# Why GCC implementation of std::vector operator[] has noexcept specifier

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, noexcept

Here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at it says that `operator[]` has ***no*** `noexcept` specifier. But If I write:

```
cout << noexcept(declval<vector<float>>()[declval<size_t>()]) << endl;
```

I get:

```
true
```

Compiled with g++.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 11.2.0.
Compilation flags: `-std=c++20` `-pedantic`.

Comment: you are basically printing `noexcept(float{});`

Comment: @康桓瑋 It seems yes, Thank you.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Maybe you right, but here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept argument to `noexcept` is a function call. Also if I write class `A` with methods: `float& f1();` and `float& f2() noexcept;` and call `noexcept` on them similarly to `vector.operator[]`, I would get `false`, and `true` respectively.

Comment: right, actually I have to admit that I am a little confused as to how `noexcept` works.